# Installing Git on CentOS failed?

Tags: git, github, centos

I am new to this, trying to install git on my VPS running on CentOS.

I tried `yum install git-core` and `yum install git` and both resulted in `No package git-core available.
Nothing to do`. I guess `git` in not in the CentOs repos.

I tried another method here: http://www.lunix.com.au/blog/install-gitosis-on-centos5/.

Running `rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm` gives me the message:

`error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0x9079f18 ctrl 0x907ad30 nrefs != 0 (download.fedora.redhat.com http)`

Is there another way to install `git`?

**UPDATE**

I get the following error after adding in the correct repo:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Error) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I think this may be due to cPanel, so I did `yum --disableexcludes=main install git`. Then it resolved the dependencies, I let it download the git package, but then it fails:

```
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:             
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
```

Comment: You could build it from source. But i highly doubt CentOS doesn't have a git package available.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well i did `yum install git` and it says theres no git package found...

Comment: that means that you did not configure the correct repository, or you did not configure the repository correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which CentOS version are you using?

"no package found" means that you did not configure the correct repository, or you did not configure the repository correctly

Your error message "skipping..." also points in that direction.

You need to google "CentOS repository for Git" ...

this yields this result:  http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2010/01/29/setting-up-git-on-centos-5-server/

Looks like you need to configure the EPEL repository as shown on that page.

Comment: thanks, I tried that and got a missing dependency error. I tried `yum install perl` and `yum install perl-git` but the first does not do anything, the second says there is no perl-git package. Updated post with error msg.

Comment: Solved this by compiling the binaries

Comment: Awesome! This saved a lot of headaches!